# what is the best way of sharing a configuration object across classes?

Tags: c++

Let us say that I have the classes M, A, B, C. M is the main class of my application (that is the one that does most of the job) and has this structure

```
class M {
  public:
    // Something here.
  private:
    Conifg config;
    A a;
    std::vector<B> bs;
    const C* c;
};
```

In a main I create an instance m of class M and I want to set my config object, say by reading it from a file. The configuration object is nothing special, it could be a protocol buffer or a simple struct.

Now, I want a, b and c to be able to access the config object, because there are some global settings that they need. These settings are global, they do not change, and are the same for each instance of A, B and C (and M). What I am currently doing, is having a static field in each class A, B and C and I am setting a copy of the configuration object for each instance of these classes. I do not want these classes to know of the existence of M. Is this the best solution? Should I perhaps think of a global config variable?

Comment: What about a shared_ptr<Config>?

Comment: The problem is not so much how I store the config object, but how I share it.

Comment: When A, B, C objects are created/located inside M, you have control to set their config as before. It seems they can be derived from a base class Configurable to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice you to use an additional static class for configuration, instead of static fields in all the classes, where you include its header in the places you want.

Implement a static constructor where you initialize all the data you want in the static members. I think this would be a better solution.

Comment: [Singletons: Solving problems you didn’t know you never had since 1995](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: @Rolice I like the idea. However I am reading the configuration in a  protocol buffer (that offers several advantages) and I would not like to write another wrapper class. I want to avoid duplicated code and I do not want to get rid of protobuf.

Comment: OK, I saw the common format. Then what is the problem to store the date in list or array in the objects (while in the static class general config), in case the structure may vary. You will have to implement function for parsing a given received object and one for accessing properties of the object... or I beg you?

You may refer to C++ templates. If you have several expected structure objects and you have a common between them, you also may create some interfaces (in C++ - fully abstract classes) and then cast each object to the interface it belongs, which will allow you to spend less code.

Comment: The link in the comments doesn't work, but I found it in the archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20110325141314/http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/

Answer (score 10):

Just pass the Config object to the A, B and C constructors (specifically, pass a *reference* to the Config object which is stored in M.

That gives you:

- testability (you can easily swap out the config object for testing purposes
- ease of reuse (you don't have "invisible" dependencies on globals that just have to be there. All A, B and C needs in order to exist are what they're given in their constructors
- flexibility (you can create different config objects to pass to different classes, if you need to)
- readability, because the person reading your code doesn't have to wonder "where does the config object come from? Who else might have changed it? Can I be sure it's been initialized at this point?". The classes A, B and C are self-contained, and can be read and understood in isolation.

But whatever you do, [don't use a singleton](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/), and try to avoid static/global data in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for flexibility, it should not happen that they will have different configs, so maybe using something global should enforce this.
I am trying to use a class S with only static methods, to be set by M and be included by A, B and C in their cpp files, similar to what suggested Rolice and Tom Kerr. I think I like that if at some point I have to add another object, say D, I can just include S. This is readable enough, because the code will look like S::get_config(), so you would know it comes from S

Comment: Please read the blog post I linked to before you start to enforce that "it should not happen" by using globals. It is a terrible idea, and *in the best case*, it buys you nothing. In the worst case, it'll cause you a lot of grief. If "it should not happen", then just don't do it. No need to involve globals or absurd "one instance only" limitations. But don't paint yourself into a corner. You don't know what requirements you'll have tomorrow. It's better to have the *option* of passing different config objects, and not using it, than making it impossible, and then, later on, needing to do it.

Comment: @stefano: on the last part, no, `S::get_config()` doesn't tell me where it comes from. When was it initialized? By whom? I know that S holds the object *now*, but that doesn't tell me whether it has been initialized, or whether it is ready for me to use. An object explicitly passed to me as a parameter indicates that "someone made sure the object is ready, and wants me to use it"

Comment: you are right, it does not tell me where it was initialized and by whom. As for being ready however, there is some machinery that can be implemented in S, to prevent returning with S::get_congig() if the object is not ready. In my case, the shared config is really unchangeable and the same for all the application, so the other concern should be minor.

Comment: Of course there are workarounds and extra plumbing that can work around the various deficiencies, but why add all that complexity just to fix a fundamentally bad idea? Why not just pass the dependencies to the class that needs it? That's simple, safe, testable, readable, flexible, easy to do, hard to break.

Answer (score 4):

I personally would rather somehow pass that config object to A B C than use global/static objects.
What about passing it (it's reference) as an argument upon construction of a b c, or setting it later via set_config() call?

Comment: This is what dependency injection is all about.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the most *maintainable* solutions for problems like these, are to use static function.  If you use some object interface, hide it behind these functions.

Here is an example.

```
namespace config {
    // public interface that is used a lot
    bool GetConfigValue(const std::string &key, std::string &val);
}

namespace config {
namespace detail {

    // detail interface that is used for setup and tear down

    class Config {
    public:
        virtual ~Config() {}
        virtual bool get(const std::string &key, std::string &val) = 0;
    };

    void RegisterConfig(Config *cfg);
    void ResetConfig();
}}
```

Honestly, you'll have to change the interface eventually, and it's going to suck.  The more you expose throughout the code, the higher risk it will be.  So keep it simple.

As background, this is a [cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) which are typically annoying to deal with.  You really don't want to pass these sorts of things around to your objects.  Research into aspect oriented programming may be interesting, as they talk about the subject a lot.